# Php SimpleXMLElement add child tags

Tags: php, xml, appendchild

I have a question regarding addChild in SimpleXMLElement. Just a clarifing one.

This piece of code:

```
$Xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<test></test>");
$Xml->addChild("child");
echo $Xml->asXML();
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <test><child/></test>
```

My question is why it doesnt produce this?->

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <test><child></child></test>
```

If I give "child" some value it shows up correctly. Im just trying to figure out why it works this way and if I have to worry about that.

Thank you all for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no contents in the tag there is no point to having the full notation. It's just a simple optimization.

There's nothing to *worry* about.